# Which are the best open/free softwares for debris flow and rock fall simulation?

Tags: natural-disasters, software, simulation

For debris flow,  Flow-R and Titan2D I'm sure are very good, both the softwares themselves and the amount of publications.

But for rock falls, it seems the Colorado Rockfall Simulation Program is not supported anymore. And from this [list](http://geotechpedia.com/Software/Tag/1548/rockfall), it is the only one that is free.

Also, for rock falls it would be good to have a software  that makes 3D simulations, using DEMs, like [RockyFor3D](http://www.ecorisq.org/ecorisq-tools).

Comment: Sorry if the question is not well tagged, but all the tags that looked right for me weren't created yet. I suggest the tags: "debris flow", "rockfall", "simulation" and "natural hazards".